# How to solve Python Zero Division error in switch condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve an expression, and getting `zero division error` while the `/` has already been resolved and not present in stack, but we are getting error while multiplying the digits which is weird.

Check the below code for refrence:

```
def reversePolishNotation(tokens):
    # Write your code here.
    operators = [ "+", "-", "*", "/" ]
    stack = []

    for token in tokens:
        if token not in operators:
            stack.append(int(token))
        else:
            firstNumber = stack.pop()
            secondNumber = stack.pop()

            switcher = {
                "+": firstNumber + secondNumber,
                "-": secondNumber - firstNumber,
                "*": firstNumber * secondNumber,
                "/": secondNumber / firstNumber
            }

            sum = switcher.get(token)
            
            stack.append(int(sum))
    
    return int(stack[-1])


resp = reversePolishNotation(["4", "-7", "2", "6", "+", "10", "-", "/", "*", "2", "+", "3", "*", "0", "*"])
```

Comment: Don't calculate the result of division for non-division operators.

Comment: Your `switcher` should really be a dictionary of functions / lambdas. As implemented currently you're performing those operations regardless of the actual one that needs to be performed.

Comment: I did not understand, what I needed to do with the dictionary of functions/lambdas. And why does this return an error, when it needs to perform multiplication only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with switcher implementation. You can do same with if-else conditions. Check the below code which returns `zero` for the given input and that don't have conflict with `zeroDivisionError`.

```
def reversePolishNotation(tokens):
    # Write your code here.
    operators = [ "+", "-", "*", "/" ]
    stack = []

    for token in tokens:
        if token not in operators:
            stack.append(int(token))
        else:
            firstNumber = stack.pop()
            secondNumber = stack.pop()

            if token == "+":
                sum = firstNumber + secondNumber
            elif token == "-":
                sum = secondNumber - firstNumber
            elif token == "/":
                sum = secondNumber / firstNumber
            else:
                sum = firstNumber * secondNumber
            
            stack.append(int(sum))
    
    return int(stack[-1])
```

Comment: An explanation of _what_ the issue is with the `switcher` implementation would improve your answer.

Answer (score 4):

As already answered, the issue is the `switcher` implementation.
With the `switcher` dictionary declared inside the loop, every time the token list is looped, the dictionary is recreated. This requires performing all the operations regardless of operator choice.

But to add an alternative you can make use of the lambda functions by declaring an `OPERATOR_SWITCHER` before the loop as follows:

```
def reversePolishNotation(tokens):
    operators = [ "+", "-", "*", "/" ]
    stack = []

    OPERATOR_SWITCHER = {
        "+": lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y),
        "-": lambda x, y: int(y) - int(x),
        "*": lambda x, y: int(x) * int(y),
        "/": lambda x, y: int(y) / int(x)
    }

    for token in tokens:
        if not token in operators:
            stack.append(token)
        else:
            firstNumber = stack.pop()
            secondNumber = stack.pop()

            operation = OPERATOR_SWITCHER.get(token)

            result = int(operation(firstNumber, secondNumber))
            stack.append(str(result))

    return int(stack[-1])
```

With that, you avoid unnecessary operations on every token iteration.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the functions that are already defined in `operator` instead of defining your own lambdas. https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: I was just trying to be nice with the "Hope it helps"... 

Comment: we try to keep answers to-the-point, and you were already being nice by volunteering your time to write a good answer :)